# RxJava: BehaviorSubject not receiving subsequent emissions from source Observable

Tags: android, rx-java, reactivex, behaviorsubject

I'm having trouble trying to use a `BehaviorSubject` (via `RxRelay.BehaviorRelay`) to store the most recent emission from a continuous `Observable`.

By 'continuous', I mean the source `Observable` is designed to emit data whenever it's underlying dataset changes.

The `BehaviorSubject` is subscribed to the source `Observable`.

It appears that once I subscribe to the `BehaviorSubject`, I only ever seem to receive the first value emitted from the source `Observable` to the `BehaviorSubject`. The source `Observable` appears to no longer emit continuously, and in fact, ceases to emit any more items.

So, here's a somewhat contrived example:

```
//A Singleton
public class DataManager {

    private Observable<List<Item>> itemsObservable;

    //A BehaviorRelay (BehaviorSubject)
    public BehaviorRelay<List<Item>> itemsRelay = BehaviorRelay.create();

    private DataManager() {

        //An Observable which emits when subscribed, and then subsequently when the underlying uri's data changes
        itemsObservable = SqlBrite.createQuery(Uri uri, ...);

        //In practice I would lazily subscribe to the relay.
        itemsObservable.subscribe(itemsRelay);
    }
}
```

Now, subscribing to the `BehaviorSubject` from somewhere:

```
// Subscribe to the BehaviorSubject
DataManager.getInstance.itemsObservable.subscribe(items -> {
    //Here, I would expect 'items' to be the most recent List<Item> emitted from the source Observable to the BehaviorSubject.
    //However, it seems like it's only ever the *first* item emitted from the source Observable to the BehaviorSubject.
    //It seems like the source Observable never emits to the BehaviorSubject more than once, despite the source's underlying 
    //dataset having changed (I am triggering this change in testing).
});
```

Comment: There could be an error emitted by the `itemsObservable` that nobody receives.

Comment: The thing is, in my testing, if I subscribe directly to the `itemsObservable` instead of to the `BehaviorSubject`, I receive a continuous stream of emissions as expected. So, I don't *think* there's an error being emitted.

Comment: Does it work if you use `BehaviorSubject` instead of `BehaviorRelay`?

Comment: I hadn't actually tested that. Testing it now, and no, it doesn't make a difference.

Comment: Could be something that you don't show. Could you create a runnable example mocking out SqlBrite?

Comment: I'm attempting to, but I can't seem to replicate this behavior (which tells me the issue is indeed something I'm doing but not showing, or within SqlBrite itself). I'll be back with more info later..

Comment: It looks like it was just a flaw in my testing. The underlying uri was not being notified of a change, which is why it wasn't emitting any new values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out there was just a flaw in my testing. The uri backing the `SqlBrite` `Observable` wasn't being notified of changes, so the `Observable` wasn't emitting any new values. There was also a bit of a red herring to do with the `Subject` being re-subscribed in an `onResume` lifecycle method.. All working as intended.